# XPATH mulitple condition to exclude some elements

Tags: xpath

I would like to parse schema data using XPATH.
Here's a simple structure.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/Product">

  <div itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/Person">
  <span itemprop="birthday" datetime="2009-05-10">May 10th 2009</span>
  </div>

  <div itemprop="name"> Product name </div>
  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Offer">
    <span itemprop="price" content="500.00"> USD 500 </span>
  </div>

</div>
```

The result I would like to parse is like this:

```
1. Category: http://www.schema.org/Product
  v name: Product name
  v Offers
      - price: USD 500
2. Category: http://www.schema.org/Person
  v birthday: May 10th 2009
```

To categorize "http://www.schema.org/Product" and "http://www.schema.org/Person", I used this code:

```
var category = $x("//*[@itemtype and not(@itemprop)]");
```

So category[0]:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/Product">

  <div itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/Person">
  <span itemprop="birthday" datetime="2009-05-10">May 10th 2009</span>
  </div>

  <div itemprop="name"> Product name </div>
  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Offer">
    <span itemprop="price" content="500.00"> USD 500 </span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Category[1]:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/Person">
  <span itemprop="birthday" datetime="2009-05-10">May 10th 2009</span>
</div>
```

Before parsing itemprop, I have to purge this one on category[0] to prevent duplicated data,

```
...
<div itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/Person">
  <span itemprop="birthday" datetime="2009-05-10">May 10th 2009</span>
  </div>
...
```

How can I exclude those things on category[0]?

```
I would like to exclude this one under category[0]-> 
Final expression I would like to make:
Select category[0] not select ([contains(@itemtype,'schema.org/') and not(@itemprop)]/descendant-or-self::*)
```

Please shed light on the matter.
Thank you:)

Comment: This isn't well formed XML input. `<div itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/Product">` Attributes in XML need to be `name="value"`.

Comment: Dear @MichaelKay,  I'm sorry for not well formed XML input. I simplified the structure to apply to many sites in common. When I looked at eBay's structure or some other site, there wasn't name="value". Does it matter to solve this question? Thank you for your reply! :)

Comment: Well it means that no-one will be able to test their answer to the question before posting it, and some people here always test their answers before posting.

Comment: I see, thanks for your reply! I should have been more careful on this posting. I'm sorry.